# select with simple column and aggregate function returning results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am brushing up my SQL knowledge and I came across an example that was supposed to proceduce an error. I am using MySQL.

The SQL statemente is like this:

```
 SELECT price, COUNT(*) As num_products
 FROM product
```

I got a result like this:

```
 preco   count(*
  100    9
```

Why this mix of simple column and aggregate working?

Comment: Can you kindly specify how the product table looks like

Comment: If this is actually working, I need to brush up my SQL knowledge as well.

Comment: @RobertKock, it all depends on how you define _working_...

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: There's nothing unsual about the table, "price" holds prices, it is a decimal and all rows have valid prices (no nulls). There are nine rows. I have only one product with a price value of 100. and it is the row with the lowest id, 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query uses aggregate function and it means your query return one group of the data. Therefore the behavior of this query is similar to query with GROUP BY statement. MySQL won't make an error if [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode is disabled in these cases. The official documentation says:

> If a query has aggregate functions and no GROUP BY clause, it cannot
>   have nonaggregated columns in the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled:

You can get more information about this behavior in [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)